# MS Access not working after swapping ODBC linked table with ODBC linked view

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2010

My company uses an SQL Server database, with Access as a front end.  One of the biggest tables on the server is called tbl_Contacts.  The primary key, "ContactID" was setup as an auto-incrementing "int" data type.  Turns out yesterday afternoon, the limits of the "int" type ran out, and no new contacts could be added to the table.

At first I tried just updating the data type to "bigint", but then Access couldn't recognize the data type and showed "Deleted" for all the fields in the Contacts table.

I read a bunch of different articles and realized that Access 2010 cannot understand the bigint data type, and that I would need to cast the field to a different type that Access could understand.

I ended up making a View of tbl_Contacts and used this SQL to modify the ContactID field, including all the other fields in the table as is.

```
CAST(ContactID AS Decimal(15, 0)) AS ContactID
```

I then renamed the old linked table in Access to tbl_Contacts_OLD, added the new ContactsView table into Access with an ODBC connection, and renamed the View to "tbl_Contacts".

I thought everything was working, because I could add new records to the table again, but it turns out some things are still not working.

**The only thing I can imagine is that other tables in my database are expecting "ContactID" to be a "Long Integer", and they aren't liking it being a "Decimal".**

When I try to use a form that adds data to a table "tbl_CallLog", which links to "tbl_Contacts", I get this error.

> Run-time error '3101'
>   The MS Access database engine cannot find a record in the table 'tbl_Contacts' with key matching field(s) 'ContactID'

Is there another data type I should be casting to that Access 2010 can recognize and use?  Is there maybe a step I still need to do, perhaps casting the decimal value to yet another data type within Access?

Do I need to convert the data type on all other tables that reference the original Contacts table so they're linked fields are now decimal data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't the best solution in the world, but I finally got my problem fixed doing the following.

My tbl_Contacts table only has 99k records in it, but due to various reasons, and the table being 20 years old, the IDENTITY SEED was at 2+ billion, the limits of the "int" datatype.  I looked through the IDs and found a gap of 120k numbers, so I used this query to reset my seed value.

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[tbl_Contacts]', RESEED, -92801);
GO

I've created several test contacts now, and the first one had the ID number -92800.

This should hold me until I can get a new CRM system in place in the middle part of the year.

Thanks for the comments, Gustav.

Answer (score 0):

*BigInt* can be understood only by Access 2016.

The data types for a record id should be either *Long* or *GUID*. *Long* is by far the most commonly used.

Comment: The IDs are "int' on SQL Server, but that translates to "Long Integer" in Access 2010.  This Access file is super old, and doesn't work properly on Access 2013 or 2016, so I keep it on 2010 until I can launch a new system later this year.  The long int numbers max out at 2. something billion, which is what my auto-increment hit, which is why I'm trying to get it to convert to a different data type.  I did notice there are gaps in the sequence that are pretty huge.  I've tried resetting the Identity Seed value on SQL Server, and re-linking that table, but it didn't work on the access side.

Comment: If values will exceed those of Long you will have to either reset these (I'm not a DBA of SQL Server so other may chime in) or, or change/add a field to hold a GUID, or convert the Access database to the ACE format (accdb files) and use Access 2016 which is able to handle BigInt given that you use the newest ODBC driver.